# How to get only country code in ngModel while using ngx-international-phone-number

Tags: angular

I'm using `ngx-international-phone-number` and I want to get only country code as response in the model from it's predefined

```
`<international-phone-number [(ngModel)]="model.country_code" placeholder="" [defaultCountry]="'th'" #country_code="ngModel" name="country_code" [allowedCountries]="['in', 'ca', 'us', 'th']">`
```

I'm not getting the desired output as +91 but it's showing undefined as output when i put `console.log()` in the main code where the model is passed.

Here is the code I'm using to create the model

```
<div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-6" [ngClass]="{ 'has-error': f.submitted && !country_code.valid }">
         <label for="country_code">Cell Number *</label>
         <international-phone-number [(ngModel)]="model.country_code" placeholder="" [defaultCountry]="'th'" [required]="false" #country_code="ngModel" name="country_code" [allowedCountries]="['in', 'ca', 'us', 'th']">
         </international-phone-number>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-6" [ngClass]="{ 'has-error': f.submitted && !cell_number.valid }">
         <label for="cell_number">Cell Number *</label>
         <input type="text" class="form-control" name="cell_number" [(ngModel)]="model.cell_number" #cell_number="ngModel" required />
         <small *ngIf="f.submitted && !cell_number.valid" class="text-danger">Cell Number is required</small>
     </div>
 </div>
```

Below is the snapshot showing that +91 is set in the model but it doesn't display in the console

[image]

Comment: Sorry, not really understanding, where are you console logging? Also you have a default country chosen, why so, if that is not what you want?

Comment: @AJT_82 I'm console logging the value in the component.ts file where the whole object is passed. I had removed the default country and tried this.

Comment: I don't see any console log anywhere in your code you are showing us, so I have no idea at what point or where you are calling it. Please provide a [mcve]